# scrapy cache only images

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looking for a way to only cache the images that get scraped.

I have the HTTPCACHE_ENABLED and am currently implementing the scrapy extention : FilesystemCacheStorage

But now it caches all url's that get scraped while only the ones that go to the image pipeline should be cached.

Another solution would be a method to cache the page but still preform a check if the scraped vallue's changed since the last scrape and ignore the images.

i've tried HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_SCHEMES but i'm not sure how i direct my url_list item in this Schemes

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging in the Documentation i found that by default it uses a DummyPolicy and changing that to the RFC2616 did exactly what i was looking for.

[Scrapy Documentation RFC2616](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#rfc2616-policy)